# Is it reasonable in Python to check for a specific type of exception using isinstance?

Tags: python, exception, introspection, dnspython

Is it reasonable in Python to catch a generic exception, then use `isinstance()` to detect the specific type of exception in order to handle it appropriately?

I'm playing around with the dnspython toolkit at the moment, which has a range of exceptions for things like a timeout, an NXDOMAIN response, etc. These exceptions are subclasses of `dns.exception.DNSException`, so I am wondering if it's reasonable, or pythonic, to catch `DNSException` then check for a specific exception with `isinstance()`.

e.g.

```
try:
    answers = dns.resolver.query(args.host)
except dns.exception.DNSException as e:
    if isinstance(e, dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN):
        print "No such domain %s" % args.host
    elif isinstance(e, dns.resolver.Timeout):
        print "Timed out while resolving %s" % args.host
    else:
        print "Unhandled exception"
```

I'm new to Python so be gentle!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's what multiple `except` clauses are for:

```
try:
    answers = dns.resolver.query(args.host)
except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
    print "No such domain %s" % args.host
except dns.resolver.Timeout:
    print "Timed out while resolving %s" % args.host
except dns.exception.DNSException:
    print "Unhandled exception"
```

Be careful about the order of the clauses: The first matching clause will be taken, so move the check for the superclass to the end.

Comment: Thanks Sven... that looks much nicer.

Answer (score 1):

From dns.resolver you can import some exceptions.
(untested code)

```
from dns.resolver import Resolver, NXDOMAIN, NoNameservers, Timeout, NoAnswer

try
    host_record = self.resolver.query(self.host, "A")
    if len(host_record) > 0:
        Mylist['ERROR'] = False
        # Do something

except NXDOMAIN:
    Mylist['ERROR'] = True
    Mylist['ERRORTYPE'] = NXDOMAIN
except NoNameservers:
    Mylist['ERROR'] = True
    Mylist['ERRORTYPE'] = NoNameservers
except Timeout:
    Mylist['ERROR'] = True
    Mylist['ERRORTYPE'] = Timeout
except NameError:
    Mylist['ERROR'] = True
    Mylist['ERRORTYPE'] = NameError
```

Comment: +1 with the answer: if the exceptions are known, it's better to use different `except` blocks. But a last `except dns.resolver.DNSException` would be wise, for handling of sub-exceptions without specific treatment (or to be sure to catch all dns errors).